# Does "Bitcoin" need to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Does "Bitcoin" need to be capitalized?  In formal writing or informal, what is the current usage?

Comment: Since it is a recently founded institution (though apparently now renamed), this is a question of what they prefer, not English guidelines. They seem to use BritCoin. Famously, the Biro company threatened to sue persons writing 'Biro' with a small 'b'.

Comment: Is that just because they were using a pencil to write it?

Answer (score 3):

Not, according to the note under **Wikipedia** article on '[Bitcoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#cite_note-11).'

> There is no uniform convention for bitcoin capitalization. Some sources use ***Bitcoin***, capitalized, to refer to the technology and network and ***bitcoin***, lowercase, to refer to the unit of account.[7] The WSJ[8] and The Chronicle of Higher Education[9] advocate use of lowercase *bitcoin* in all cases, however. [emphasis added]

Accordingly, Wikipedia by its own statement, "… follows the latter convention," that is, the "use of lowercase *bitcoin* in all cases."

[EDIT]
*Clarification:* The question being 'Does bitcoin **need** to be capitalized," the answer "Not" means that it is not necessary; it does not mean it is incorrect to do so. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

- Concept and network, capitalised: ***Bitcoin*** as in *the Bitcoin Foundation* or *Should the banks allow Bitcoin to ...*
- Currency, lower case: ***bitcoin*** as in *I paid a bitcoin for this*
- Currency symbol, all capitals: ***BTC*** as in *Price: 1BTC*

**[Bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq#what-is-bitcoin)** uses capitalised Bitcoin to refer to the concept and lowercase for the actual currency.

**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin)**

> Production 25 bitcoins per block (approximately every ten minutes) until mid 2016.
>
> Subunit
>  10−8  satoshi[2]
>  10−6  bit or μBTC
>  10−3  mBTC
>
> Symbol BTC, XBT
>
> *There is no uniform convention for bitcoin capitalization. Some sources use Bitcoin, capitalized, to refer to the technology and network and bitcoin, lowercase, to refer to the unit of account. The [WSJ](http://blogs.wsj.com/moneybeat/2014/03/14/bitbeat-is-it-bitcoin-or-bitcoin-the-orthography-of-the-cryptography/) and The Chronicle of Higher Education advocate use of lowercase bitcoin in all cases, however. This article follows the latter convention.*

Comment: WP has a clear statement on this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#cite_note-11

Comment: I know. I quoted it

Comment: Ah. So did you I see

Comment: Sooner than that :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [en.bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Introduction#Capitalization_.2F_Nomenclature) both forms are acceptable depending on context:

Capitalization / Nomenclature

> - **Since *Bitcoin* is both a currency and a protocol**, capitalization can be confusing. Accepted practice is to use *Bitcoin* (singular with an upper case letter B) to label the protocol, software, and community, while
> - *bitcoins* (with a lower case b) to label units of the currency.

Anonymity:

> - When it comes to the *Bitcoin network* itself, there are no "accounts" to set up, and no e-mail addresses, user-names or passwords are required to hold or *spend bitcoins.*

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago, the technology magazine where I worked wrote a lengthy feature article on the Bitcoin phenomenon, and we took great pains in the story to distinguish between *Bitcoin* as a currency or concept on the one hand and individual (imaginary) *bitcoins*—that is, units of currency in the Bitcoin system—on the other.

Unfortunately, many occurrences of the word were ambiguous, so we had to make a series of close calls about whether to put a particular instance of the word in the initial-cap pile or in the lowercase pile. When we published the story, several readers wrote in to complain that we evidently had no idea whether to capitalize the word or not, since it appeared sometimes capped and sometimes not.

So we went back to our in-house style guide and removed the elaborate explanation for when to capitalize *Bitcoin* and when to lowercase it, and replaced it with the simple (and arbitrary) rule to lowercase *bitcoin* in all occurrences. The result: Readers stopped complaining about our inconsistency; and (not insignificantly) we never heard a peep from legal representatives of the Bitcoin enterprise.